# gradle dependencies: what "classpath" keyword means exactly and where it is documented?

Tags: java, gradle

I've did web search for "gradle classpath site:stackoverflow.com" and "gradle classpath" and found relevant info in only:
[Gradle: What is the difference between classpath and compile dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34286407/gradle-what-is-the-difference-between-classpath-and-compile-dependencies)

In the answer by Teng-pao Yu it is written:

> compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.0.5.Final' is a module
>   dependency declaration. The compile configuration (which is now
>   deprecated by the implementation configuration.) is merely a keyword
>   for Implementation only dependencies. It is not a keyword describing
>   which type of dependency it is (by type here I'm following the three
>   types defined in the tutorial, i.e. module, file, and project.)

So as I understood `classpath` is also keyword. I've tried to find its` meaning in gradle docs:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html

And some others referenced in it:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management_for_java_projects.html
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html
https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/variant_model.html
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html

Also:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/dsl/ScriptHandler.html
https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/Classpath.html
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html

There are mentions of 'compileClasspath'. If `classpath` keyword is merely deprecated as `compile` one, why is it absent from docs?

P.S. I mean like in:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
   }
}
```

ADDED after answer:

search for getBuildscript() in gradle source code:
[image: search for getBuildscript() in gradle source code]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> So as I understood `classpath` is also keyword

This is incorrect. `classpath`, `compile`, `implementation`, `api`, and many more are all [**configurations**](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html). Configurations in Gradle are tree-like meaning typically each one extends from some parent:

[image: configuration tree]

Source: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph

For example, using the `implementation` *configuration*, when you do the following in your `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9")
}
```

You are actually doing:

```
project.getDependencies().add("implementation", "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9")
```

The former uses the [Gradle DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/index.html) while the latter uses the Gradle API directly.

> If `classpath` keyword is merely deprecated as `compile` one, why is it absent from docs?

The `compile` *configuration* is deprecated as noted [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html). The `classpath` configuration is still used, but typically only used with the [`buildscrpt { }`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:applying_plugins_buildscript) block.

So for your example:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1")
    }
}
```

Desugars to:

```
project.getBuildscript().getDependencies().add("classpath", "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1")
```

Comment: thank you! I'm trying to find your last line in gradle source - see updated end of my question (picture from IDEA). Is it seen on the picture where that line is called? or should I search differently?

Comment: search for `getBuildscript().getDependencies()` return nothing and for `getDependencies()` returns 100+ entries so I hope to find code in question from `getBuildscript()` entry.

Comment: You aren't going to find 1:1 of the snippets I've added above. Gradle is heavily abstracted. Best bet to find the lines is to write a plugin that does the above and test/debug to trace the code paths.

Comment: I would also appreciate your help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60070739/plugin-request-for-plugin-already-on-the-classpath-must-not-include-a-version, start with added 2 at the end. That question was before I started to dig in and wrote this one.
P.S. I wrote above before your response in comment. I guess answer (at least to ADDED 2) would be same?