# Different gradle dependencies in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am new at Android programming. Can anybody tell me how the difference in the use of `dependencies` between the `classpath` and the implementation in Android Studio. In tutorial at Google using dependencies with implementation, but in my Android Studio is using `classpath`?

Comment: [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management_for_java_projects.html)

Comment: and [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34286407/gradle-what-is-the-difference-between-classpath-and-compile-dependencies)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle: What is the difference between classpath and compile dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34286407/gradle-what-is-the-difference-between-classpath-and-compile-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

If buildscript itself needs something to run, use `classpath.`

If your project needs something to run, use `implementation.`

The `buildscript{}` block is for the build.gradle itself.

And here is the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies)